# Different subnet for different device types

Tags: networking, wireless-router, subnet

I have noticed a certain pattern in a wireless network. It goes something like this:

- All mobile devices (Android and iOS) take the subnet `10.8.5.x`.
- All laptops (Windows and Linux) take the subnet `10.8.3.x`.

It might be pure coincidence, but I like to believe there is something else going on. If such mechanism on the router (i.e. providing different ip subnets to different device types) exists, how is it called? And how is the router able to distinguish between the different device types, isn't the MAC address everything it gets from the device?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not ask your network admin?  He is the only one who would know the correct answer.  All we can do here is speculate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this from microsoft dhcp servers and its called DHCP device classes.
You can read more about that here (http://blogs.technet.com/b/teamdhcp/archive/2012/09/22/using-dhcp-policies-to-set-different-lease-durations-for-different-device-types.aspx) or just look for other information on this.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

The first few bytes of a MAC address (unless overridden) supply manufacturer and device type that a discriminating DHCP server could use to allocate devices into different address ranges.

The subnet could be large enough that both address ranges could be within the same subnet.  So, it may not actually be different subnets.  Further, trying to have a router administer multiple subnets could be a difficult thing to configure, but might be available on higher-end access points or routers.